# Double Checked Locking *besides* Singletons

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, lock-free, memory-fences

I've been searching the interweb for a while now to find a discussion about DCL that doesn't involve the singleton pattern. So instead, I'm just going to ask exactly what I want to know.

Is DCL appropriate here?

```
std::shared_ptr<bool> mybool_smart_ptr(new bool); // initialized to false in main thread
std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> mtx(new std::mutex);
std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable_any> cond(new std::condition_variable_any);


void proceed_to_work() {
    if(*mybool_smart_ptr)
         return;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*mtx);
    // if DCL is broken, would a fence here help?
    if(*mybool_smart_ptr)
         return;
    cond->wait(lock);
}
```

Any writers to `*mybool_smart_ptr` do so lock-free. The work which the spawned threads do is all or nothing, that's what they wait for.

Comment: The acronym for Double Checked Locking is *DLC* ? Why the inversion? ;)

Comment: I actually assumed you were a gamer and blamed muscle memory ;)

Comment: If your locks are recursive, you blew the stack.
If your locks are non-recursive you deadlocked.
If your locks are non-recursive and trap recursive calls you threw an unhandled exception.

What on earth are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @DrPizza You had me really confused until I realized not everyone might assume `lock()` implies a scoped lock that is released on destruction.

Comment: That doesn't help. You have a recursive call to wait() that'll still call scoped_lock() on each pass.

Comment: @DrPizza SOB!...I didn't notice that when I gave things "simpler" names. I'll rename the function def.

Comment: `scoped_lock();` locks and unlocks immediately, which is fairly useless. You need a variable for the lifetime to extend to the end of the function.

Comment: Well, OK, it no longer blows up, I just no longer understand what it is you're trying to do. Can you show real code with a real question?

Comment: The semantics of `mybool_smart_ptr`, `scoped_lock()`, and `wait()` affect the answer too, of course.

Comment: Compile-able code added

Comment: You need to guard against spurious wakeups: `while (!*mybool_smart_ptr) { cond->wait(); }` (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)

Comment: Does `*mybool_smart_ptr` ever get set back to false after it becomes true?

Comment: @AlanStokes I never noticed that in the standard; how does a thread "spuriously" wakeup?

Comment: No, setting `*mybool_smart_ptr` is disallowed by the documentation.

Comment: *setting back to false.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup

Comment: That doesn't touch on *how/why* that happens